# Extract gnutls library files of tar.xz and tar.lz for ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: tar, ubuntu-10.04, gnutls

I am very new to linux platform and I want to extract gnutls for ubuntu. If I do,

```
$ls
```

then, it will show these files below.

```
gnutls-3.2.1.tar.lz
gnutls-3.2.1.tar.lz.sig
gnutls-3.2.1.tar.xz
gnutls-3.2.1.tar.xz.sig
```

When I give command,

```
$ tar -xvf gnutls-3.2.1.tar.xz
```

I get output,

```
tar: xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I want to extract these files.

1. Why there are two types of formats given? - xz and lz
2. Why there are signature files? - .sig
   How to verify it? I tried to verification by `gpgv <filename>.sig` command, it says public key   is not found.
3. I need a separate utility package? I saw one, 'xz-utils_4.999' but it is **beta**. 
   http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xz.1.html
4. Any other stable utility package? From where and how can I download it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Why there are two types of formats given? - xz and lz*

Only for convenience, so that people can download the one for which they have appropriate tools available/installed. Remember that most 'linux' libraries are intended for use on other unix-like platforms also (e.g. the BSDs, Solaris, AIX, OSX even). It cannot be assumed that more recent tools like xz are readily available in every platform.

*I need a separate utility package?*

Yes, the error message from tar is telling you that it cannot find the xz command:

```
tar: xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
```

You identified correctly the package to install, `xz-utils`. If you tried to extract the .lz archive, it would comlain that it cannot find `lzip` instead (and you would install the lzip package).

There's not much difference, lzip is the older LZMA standard, xz is the newer LZMA2. The label 'beta' is always subjective. In this context I would not worry!

*Why there are signature files?*

So that people can be sure the archive they downloaded was published by the person they expect. It is to guard against the possibility that a hacker could gain access to the site (or a mirror) then add some malicious code to the sources in the archive.

*How to verify it?*

You got that command fine, but what you need to understand is that you have to tell GnuPG which keys you trust. Typically, you would take the public key (usually .asc or .txt) files published by the author(s) and import them to your gpg keyring. On the GnuTLS downloads page:

> All the releases are signed with [Nikos'](http://members.hellug.gr/nmav/pgpkeys.asc) or [Simon's](http://josefsson.org/key.txt) OpenPGP key.

So you could do something like:

```
wget -O- http://josefsson.org/key.txt | gpg --import
wget -O- http://members.hellug.gr/nmav/pgpkeys.asc | gpg --import
```

Another way is when people publish only their RSA Key ID, which can be imported from commonly known gpg keyservers. For example, you could import my public key like this:

```
gpg --recv-key 15C4D63E
```

For most default gpg configurations, that should obtain the specified key from a public keyserver (probably keys.gnupg.net).

Afterwards, gpg should report a 'good signature' from either of those authors, but expect it still to show a warning:

```
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
```

This just means that there exists no chain of trust (based on the keys you have marked as trusted in your keyring) to say that this is the **correct** key for the named person. It could be the key of a hacker instead.

At some point you have to be confident that the key you obtain came from the right person, but exactly what to trust and when is something for each person to research and decide for themselves, based on your own level of paranoia, or current purposes.

Personally, I do not bother to verify source archives unless I am planning to redistribute something built from them.

Comment: An attacker could easily change the signature files.

Comment: @MatthewMitchell Sure, an attacker can change the signature files, but cannot easily forge a valid signature for a key they do not control. This is why public keys are often published through a different host or a public keyserver. It's also why it is best to add them once to your trusted keys, and why people counter-sign each other's keys etc. to build a web of trust, so that people don't need to blindly accept that the key published on a given web page is correct for the claimed author.

Comment: For those reading "lzip is the older LZMA standard, xz is the newer LZMA2" be aware that lzip and xz are separate projects and xz appears to be objectively worse in many ways (including compression ratio) than lzip, so lzip should be preferred if you have the option (as per https://www.nongnu.org/lzip/xz_inadequate.html which is biased, but AFAICT correct)

Answer (score 35):

```
tar --lzip -xvf gmp-5.1.2.tar.lz
```

Worked for me

As mentioned below in the comments, you might have to install the library before the command will work:

```
sudo apt-get install lzip
```

Comment: I wanted to unzip the same file :P

Answer (score 13):

1. Install `lzip`.
2. Launch the following command that creates `xxx.tar` file and deletes the `xxx.tar.lz` file after extracting:

   ```
   lzip -d xxx.tar.lz
   ```
3. Launch the following command to finally untar:

   ```
   tar zxvf xxx.tar
   ```

Answer (score 6):

You can resolve with:

```
# The lzip page is: http://lzip.nongnu.org/lzip.html
# Download the lzip:
wget http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/lzip/lzip-1.15.tar.gz
# decompress:
tar xvf lzip-1.15.tar.gz
cd lzip-1.15
# configure / build
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
# install
sudo make install

# now you can unzip with 
tar xvf gmp-5.1.3.tar.lz
```

Comment: this works presuming the bin subdirectory of the directory specified with prefix (so, /usr/bin here) is on the bash PATH.  if it isn't, one would need to add it to PATH in one's .bashrc file (or otherwise).

Comment: @dbliss, yes, not just the path, it presumes you have `wget`, `tar` and `sudo` too. but I'm curious which unix like OS doesn't have the /usr/bin on path by default.

Comment: /usr/bin is the default, but that raises the question why you used the `--prefix` option at all.  i was more concerned with my case (and the vast majority of the cases in which that option is used), where a non-default directory is specified with `--prefix`.  i used your code, and then realized i had to add the non-default directory to my path.  the other presumptions you mentioned -- that you need `wget`, for example -- are obvious and not worth mentioning.

Comment: when I run the "sudo make install" command I get the following error `if [ ! -d "/usr/bin" ] ; then install -d -m 755 "/usr/bin" ; fi
install -m 755 ./lzip "/usr/bin/lzip"
install: /usr/bin/lzip: Operation not permitted
make: *** [install-bin] Error 71` any ideas why? I'm on OSX

Comment: I'm not a OSX user, but I think OSX do not use `sudo` ... I think it uses `brew` instead... but you need to understand what `sudo` do... `sudo` targets "super user do ...". so, you need to execute the `make install` as super user in your OSX. I think it simple as replace `sudo` by `brew`... but again... I'm not a OSX user.

Comment: Using `tar xvf myfile.tar.lz` at the end didn't work, but `lzip -d myfile.tar.lz` did. Thank you!

Comment: `tar (GNU tar) 1.29` works for me... you can try it... get it in http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/ and build it as same `./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install`

Comment: This is perfect

Answer (score 2):

First to extract xz files, you need install xz-utils. If are in debian or ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install xz-utils`

Now you can extract files using:

`tar -xJf file_name.xz`

Answer (score 0):

LZIP is available in [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html). You may install lzip (from Archive branch in cygwin's setup) and tar (from Base branch). After that you can do

```
tar --lzip -xvf your_file.tar.lz
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For tar.lz, if your tar doesn't support --lzip

```
tar xf filename.tar.lz --use-compress-program lrunzip
```