# installing NTL with GMP

Tags: c++, macos, unix, gmp, ntl

The problem I am having is installing NTL with GMP on my mac (Sierra).

These are the steps I have taken following [this](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-unix.html) tutorial

1) I downloaded  [Unix: ntl-10.3.0.tar.gz](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/download.html)

2) double clicked file to create the ntl-10.3.0.tar.gz folder in my downloads

3)

```
cd ~/Downloads/ntl-10.3.0/src
./configure
make
```

This gives me an error, because I guess I didn’t have GMP installed yet:

```
gen_gmp_aux.cpp:26:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
#include <gmp.h>
```

4) There are instructions on [this](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-gmp.html) page that describe how to install GMP

5) I download gmp-6.1.2.tar.lz from [here](https://gmplib.org/). (Not that it matters but notice the extension is different in the instructions … I’m mentioning everything just in case)

6) 
I find out that .lz extensions need the [lzip command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976696/extract-gnutls-library-files-of-tar-xz-and-tar-lz-for-ubuntu-10-04-lts):

7)

```
brew install lzip
cd ~/Downloads
lzip -d gmp-6.1.2.tar.lz 
tar -xf gmp-6.1.2.tar
cd gmp-6.1.2
```

8)

Note: 
Reading the instructions, I don’t configure with —prefix=$HOME/sw because I want it installed in the /usr/local directory, not my home directory

```
./configure
make
make check
```

No errors come up, every thing is green and says ‘passed’

9)

```
make install
```

10)

Back to NTL

```
cd ~/Downloads/ntl-10.3.0/src/
make
```

I get the same error as before:

```
gen_gmp_aux.cpp:26:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
#include <gmp.h>
```

11)

I look in my directory

```
ls -la /usr/local/include/
```

and found gmp.h there where it should be

12)

I create a simple .cpp file to test it (basically just main with the associated include)

```
g++ someFile.cpp -lgmp
```

with this at the top

```
#include <gmp.h>
```

and it doesn’t seem to find it, same fatal error message.

Other people seem to have run into this issue also (all I could find was years ago)
[one of the guys](https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/32) did this:

```
brew uninstall gmp
brew install gmp
```

Following suit, I also did, then tried making the NTL again and it still doesn’t work…

I know I can put a flag in to not use GMP in the build:

> You can also supply the option --disable-shared to the configure script, if you only want static libraries. However, if you ultimately want to build NTL as a shared library, then you must also buld GMP as a shared library.

but I would really like to.

What am I doing wrong?
any suggestions?

I thought about sending a [bug report](https://gmplib.org/gmp-man-6.0.0a.pdf), but I don't think it's a bug, it's with my configuration.

Comment: 10 days later with zero ideas for a solution, I figure this is a good time to take it directly to GMP. I very thoroughly filled out all of the things they requested on the link I provided above, and they responded by letting me know I sent it to the wrong group of people in their company (ok, I understand), then putting me on a spam list so I couldn't send it to the place they instructed, which was also the email that they replied from, different than the one I originally sent it to  ... um ... was there something else I supposed to do? that was rude of GMP, Don't look for a solution there!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem with installing NTL can be solved by editing the file.txt in /src directory. You may try to replace `@{GMP_XXX}` with an appropriate directory (e.g. `/usr/local/`, `/usr/local/include/`, `/usr/local/lib/`) in following strings:

```
GMP_PREFIX=@{GMP_PREFIX}

GMP_INCDIR=@{GMP_INCDIR}
\#directory containing gmp.h if using GMP 

GMP_LIBDIR=@{GMP_LIBDIR}
\#directory containing libgmp.a if using GMP
```

Moreover, [this tutorial](http://thindot.blogspot.ru/2015/06/ntl-library-symbols-not-found-for.html) could be quite useful.

Comment: I do appreciate the post ... I hard coded the directory paths, I also tried following instructions on the link you provided, but unfortunately the error he was getting is different than my own, so it didn't solve my problem
... I do not understand why when I hard code the path to the gmp.h file that it does not recognize the #include <gmp.h> ... so many hours spent on this, and there ought to be a very simple solution

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. When I used the *make* command, the result just show that it couldn't find the <gmp.h> header file.
My solution to address this problem is to install the *gmp* manually instead of using *brew install gmp* command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).